# How to redirect traffic from reverse proxy to ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, traefik, k3s, harbor

I'm on a University project and we have a k3s cluster. We are trying to install harbor as our internal registry with helm. We are forced to use a nginx reverse-proxy running on port 80 and 443. I have tried to use nodePort and redirect all requisitions comming from https://dns/harbor to the nodePort running it and hasn't work. I switched the approach to use my traefik ingress running on ports 8000 and 8443 and works perfectly inside the cluster, but when I try to make the redirection it doesn't work as well. Also they have a firewall running and the two open ports are 80 and 443. Is there a way to work around these limitations or I will need to open a ticket for them to open my ingress ports?

nginx conf when using nodePort:

```
location /harbor/ {
        rewrite ^/harbor/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass  https://127.0.0.1:30443;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 
        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

helm portal nginx when using nodePort

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "{{ template "harbor.portal" . }}"
  labels:
{{ include "harbor.labels" . | indent 4 }}
data:
  nginx.conf: |+
    worker_processes auto;
    pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }
    http {
        client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_body_temp;
        proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;
        fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;
        uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;
        scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;
        server {
    {{- if .Values.internalTLS.enabled }}
            {{- if .Values.ipFamily.ipv4.enabled}}
            listen {{ template "harbor.portal.containerPort" . }} ssl;
            {{- end }}
            {{- if .Values.ipFamily.ipv6.enabled}}
            listen [::]:{{ template "harbor.portal.containerPort" . }} ssl;
            {{- end }}
            # SSL
            ssl_certificate /etc/harbor/ssl/portal/tls.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/harbor/ssl/portal/tls.key;

            # Recommendations from https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html
            ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
            {{- if .Values.internalTLS.strong_ssl_ciphers }}
            ssl_ciphers ECDHE+AESGCM:DHE+AESGCM:ECDHE+RSA+SHA256:DHE+RSA+SHA256:!AES128;
            {{ else }}
            ssl_ciphers '!aNULL:kECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AESGCM:RSA+AESGCM:kECDH+AES:ECDH+AES:RSA+AES:';
            {{- end }}
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
            ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    {{- else }}
            {{- if .Values.ipFamily.ipv4.enabled }}
            listen {{ template "harbor.portal.containerPort" . }};
            {{- end }}
            {{- if .Values.ipFamily.ipv6.enabled}}
            listen [::]:{{ template "harbor.portal.containerPort" . }};
            {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
            server_name  localhost;
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            gzip on;
            gzip_min_length 1000;
            gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
            gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
            location /devcenter-api-2.0 {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /swagger-ui-index.html;
            }
            location /harbor/ {
            rewrite ^/harbor/(.*) /$1 break;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }
            location = /index.html {
                add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
                sub_filter 'base href="/"' 'base href="/harbor/"';
                sub_filter_once on;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you paste your nginx location block that you have configured for nodePort